# How to render one html file from several html in a loop?

Tags: python, flask

I need to render one long html file from multiple simple html files.

I know that the sample below can be implemented easier, but I have good reason to do it this way (complicated html template with dozens of input parameters).

Sample code (in this case only the first subpage is rendered, as expected):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

items = [['item#1', 123],
         ['item#2', 124],
         ['item#3', 125]]

@app.route("/")
def table():
    for item in items:
        return render_template('table.html', name=item[0], sn=item[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

table.html:

```
<body>
<h3> {{ name }} </h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>SN</td>
        <td>{{ sn }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Expected output:

```
Item#1
SN  123

Item#2
SN  124

Item#3
SN  125
```

Do you have any idea, how to do it?

Comment: I think you need to do a Jinja for loop in the `table.html` file instead.

Comment: I tried it also (with included table.html), but only child html page can be called, as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return multiple times.

```
def table():
    for item in items:
        # this will return only the first item
        return render_template('table.html', name=item[0], sn=item[1])
```

You need to change your flask code to something like this:

```
def table():
    return render_template('table.html', items=items)
```

And then change your HTML code with a `for` loop:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for item in items %}
        <td>{{ item[0] }}</td>
        <td>SN {{ item[1] }}</td>
        {% endfor %} 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the easier way, I mentioned above. But: 1) the html is complicated with many calculated parameters for each instance; 2) I would like to reuse the code for single page and multiple pages (in a fact, for print / print all)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot return/render multiple times. The only way to print the entire array is by putting a for loop in the HTML file.

Comment: OK, but it leads to the proposal you mentioned above. This is clear, but in my case very complicated ... or maybe I could try use list of kwargs to predefine the data and then render it at once. Do you have an idea how to handle it in jinja2? I'll try it tomorrow and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

```
items = [{'name': 'item#1', 'sn': 123},
         {'name': 'item#2', 'sn': 124},
         {'name': 'item#3', 'sn': 125}]

@app.route("/")
def table():
    for item in items:
        return render_template('table.html', items=items)
```

and

```
{% for item in items %}
<h3> {{ item.name }} </h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>SN</td>
        <td>{{ item.sn }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```